# Unable to update main form control from subclass

Tags: c#

Attempt #2.

I'm attempting to call functions within two classes. One function to obtain data and call function B in class B to display the data through a Windows Form application.

```
    //Class B containing function B
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GUI_Server
{
    public partial class ChatServer : Form
    {

        private delegate void EnableDelegate(bool enable);
        private static ChatServer CHT = new ChatServer();

        public ChatServer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServerBackBone.test();
        }

        public static void TestConnectivity(string text)
        {
            CHT.TestLabel.Text = text;
        }
    }
} // Assume Class B
```

and the following is Class A and function A

```
   using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;


namespace GUI_Server
{
    class ServerBackBone
    {


        private static ChatServer CHT = new ChatServer();
        public static void test()
        {
            ChatServer.TestConnectivity("test");


        }


    }
}
```

So, what is going on here is that the form is being loaded, calling a static function within class A to contact class B > function B to update a label on the main window... The problem lays with updating the label with the new text.

Stepping through the code shows that all functions are successfully called & expected text is passed through to the function.

Although, when pressing F5 to start debugging said application, Diagnostic tools show the following message:

> The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly

The diagnostic hub output shows:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

General output shows:

> The thread 0x20c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 0x1624 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> 'GUI Server.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: GUI Server.vshost.exe):
>   Loaded 'c:\users\shaiya\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\GUI
>   Server\GUI Server\bin\Debug\GUI Server.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>
> The thread 0x20fc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 0xae8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Application successfully runs after these messages show. Stepping through shows now errors, nor do breakpoints. Label is not updated in the main control either

Completely new project. Only element on the actual form interface is the label with the property renamed to TestLabel.

```
 this.TestLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // TestLabel
            // 
            this.TestLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.TestLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 70);
            this.TestLabel.Name = "TestLabel";
            this.TestLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
            this.TestLabel.TabIndex = 0;
            this.TestLabel.Text = "label1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that `this` in `Form1_Load` and `CHT` in `TestConnectivity` are the same object. They would have to be, because it is `this` that you are trying to update.

Comment: That maybe the case. The block and having to use this method is that i'm using Static classes functionality in the main application when it's back up and running. Work around to keep static?

Comment: Change your `public static void Test()` to a `public static string Test()` that returns the value you want to use on the form. If it's asynchronous, you can `await` or use event listeners

Comment: That'll solve the issue with the current one without a doubt, the problem which springs to mind is the fact I will be eventually using sockets to send/receive data, both integers and strings.. With the examples seen for Sockets, it uses a Callback function with returns nothing and can be called at any time, just how would one go about listening in on an event which uses a separate function as a callback that is running in the background? Which will also update the main form when data is received?